# CMake: Should changes to libraries linked by "target_link_libraries" be automatically detected?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using `target_link_libraries` to link external libraries to my application. But when one of the linked libraries changes, the `make` command does not detect and link the changed libraries again. Is there anything I have to include in the `CMakeLists.txt` file to observe and detect library changes?

Answer (score 2):

CMake doesn't have this feature.  Nor does it have a feature to detect changes in system-level header files (in `/usr/include`).  It's probably not a good idea to add such features either, as it would slow down the common case.  I suggest you just do a clean build after you have updated your system libraries.